# How do I partition table over two columns?

Tags: postgresql, partition, database-partitioning, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

Table T1 has cols - app_id,start_time,end_time,value.
We have multiple applications and would like to partition tables by app_id and start_time (weekly partitions).
This is how the child partitions should look like

```
T1_part1_2018 
app_id start_time end_time   value
1     10-10-2018  10-11-2018 garbage

T2_part2_2018 
app_id start_time end_time   value
2     10-10-2018  10-11-2018 garbage

T1_part1_2019
app_id start_time end_time   value
1     10-10-2019  10-11-2019 garbage

T2_part2_2019
app_id start_time end_time   value
2     10-10-2019  10-11-2019 garbage
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the sub-partition mechanism :

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html
- https://blog.dbi-services.com/postgresql-partitioning-8-sub-partitioning/

Which partition have to be the mother of the other one is entirely up too your needs : if you never need to request the data of more than one app_id, I would recommend make the app_id the mother partition key.

EDIT :
And here is the pg_partman extension project page : 
https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_partman/doc/pg_partman.html

Comment: Is there no other option other than sub-partitioning? I am concerned about the complexity of managing multiple client partitions, scalability and performance.

Comment: If you want something easier to manage it : https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_partman/doc/pg_partman.html is the extension for you ;)